# Plotting a Grouped Pandas Dataframe in Python

Tags: python, pandas

Well, I don't have reputation to post a photo, so this will be extremely difficult to explain, but I have a grouped dataframe which has 9 unique facilities and 7 years (2008-2014) for each facility.  For each grouped facility/year, I have three column values (359.89 Etiologic, 359.89 Comorbid, Neither Etiologic Nor Comorbid) which sum to one for each facility/year combination as they represent the percent of total 359.89 Etiologic, 359.89 Comorbid, and Neither Etiologic Nor Comorbid totals, respectively.

And I got to that data through the following:

```
df3= df.groupby(['NCI_Facility_Name', 'NCI_Compliance_Year','UDS_35989_FLAG'])['PatCode'].count()


df3 = df3.unstack().apply(lambda x: x/x.sum(),axis=1).fillna('0')
```

My goal is to plot the year (x) against the '359.89 Etiologic' column values (y) for each facility.  I am having trouble because any plot that I attempt plots all three columns against an x value for every facility/year combination.  I'd prefer to have 7 years on the x-axis: 2008-2014 and 0 through 1 on the y-axis and want to plot the year against only the 359.89 Etiologic values.

Comment: Well for axis labeling you can change the limits on the axis using: `pylab.ylim([y1,y1])`

Comment: Feel free to create some graphics and host them on a third party image hosting site. If you provide a link, users with higher reputation can then edit the image into your question.